# How to convert a GCM Intent Service to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, migrate

I'm migrating an old app from GCM to FCM and I have converted most things but I get to this service and I'm at a little bit of a loss to how I should proceed--I'm finding nothing in the migration documentation (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) I see that I'd probably need to change the manifest entry as well (`<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />`).

Here's the old service:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GCMIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {...}

    @Override
    public void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {...}

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {...}

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {...}
}
```

Any guidelines are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a really old implementation of GCM. [`GCMBaseIntentService` has been deprecated](https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/51) even before FCM was released and was replaced with [`GcmListenerService`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService)).

The one shown in the GCM-FCM migration is in line with the more recent version of GCM (using `GcmListenerService`). You'll have to use [`FirebaseMessagingService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) for FCM now.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks so much